# whereDate in query compares date differently than in the code directly

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I already described the situation ([Trying to get Carbon timestamps in different timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70270775/trying-to-get-carbon-timestamps-in-different-timezones/70271058#70271058)), but I've got another problem now.
As I described earlier, there are multiple entries in MySQL with UTC 'created_at' timestamps. I need to retrieve today's entries for relevant projects according to a project's timezone.
If I compare timestamps directly:

```
$entry->created_at >= Carbon::today('Europe/Moscow')
```

then I get proper result (true). Even though the entry was made yesterday in UTC, it is considered to be made today according to Moscow timezone.

But when I make this query:

```
Entry::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today('Europe/Moscow'))
```

Eloquent doesn't retrieve the entry made in 22:30 in UTC.
What would a proper query look like?

Comment: have you tried this  Entry::whereDate('created_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now('Europe/moscow'));

Comment: @Bhargav Rangani, yes, I tried this one. But it didn't work, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a simple Artisan command to output the following :

```
Carbon::today('Europe/Moscow');
```

and then

```
Carbon::today('Europe/London');
```

and you will see that they are the same - both will output :

```
2021-12-08 00:00:00
```

That's because the day starts at the same time (00:00:00) in every timezone.

What you want to be doing is getting the start of today (in your relevant timezone) and then converting that into UTC (because that's what you've got in your database) :

```
Carbon::today('Europe/Moscow')->setTimezone("UTC");
```

if you echo that, the result you get is :

```
2021-12-08 21:00:00
```

So the query will return an entry created at 22:30 UTC as being created "today" for the purposes of a Moscow project but not, say, for a Los Angeles project.

Comment: Yes, but if I make direct comparison in the code, it compares correctly. But it doesn't work if I make a query from DB, even doing like this:
where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today('Europe/Moscow')->setTimezone('UTC')
Could you please give example of a proper Eloquent query?

Comment: I have tested it and it is working fine - I've set one of my users to have an updated_at of "2021-12-08 23:30:00" and used $user = User::where('updated_at', '>=', Carbon::today('Europe/Moscow')->setTimezone("UTC"))->first(); to retrieve them with no issue. If I change their updated_at time to 18:00:00 they do not get returned.